# What is a Self join and how does it works? I do know it is used to join a table to itself, I am trying to understand the working mechanism behind it

Tags: mysql, self-join

Why the o/p is different if I self join the table using a.b instead of a.c? Moreover, why the o/p is Y is equal to 1 and not 2?

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    B INT,
    C CHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,"X"),(2,"X"),(3,"Y"),(1,"T"),(2,"T");

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    A;

SELECT 
    a.c, COUNT(a.c) AS c1
FROM
    A a
        JOIN
    A a1 ON a.c = a1.c
GROUP BY a.c;
```

Comment: You  are simple using the table twice. So think of two copies joined on each other. For a count you are better off doing this: `SELECT  a.c, COUNT(a.c) AS count FROM  A a GROUP BY a.c;`

Comment: In your case, one table a is used to list column c, and the a1 gets the count of column c. Since you are joined on the column it would be equivalent to doing `select count(c) from A where c = 'X, Y, T....)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My doubt is if we are joining table with itself shouldn't we expect each value record to be appeared twice or am I missing something over here?

Comment: The reason why the results are what they are is that's how the language is defined. Explain why you think the result should be the same, with justification referring to authoritative documentation. Otherwise we can't address your misconceptions & you are just asking for yet another presentation of the language plus a bespoke tutorial & moreover while not knowing what you already misunderstand. [ask] [help] PS A [mre] is not just some code. PS When isolated & clear this will be a faq. General self-join is a faq. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Yes, the way  you have it you  will receive a count  for each row. The t,x ,y values should have a consistent count associated. So t should always be a count of two, but will occur twice as there are two t rows. Hence why the group by is better. You could also do a select distinct column c, then you would not receive the duplicates.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming? "What is a self join" is something that is covered in tons of tutorials out there. if you don't understand them, please explain further where you are stuck

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your reply and apologies for delayed response. I am new to SQL and tried to research a lot about Self-join before posting it over here. 9 of 10 examples I came across used the same problem of finding the reporting manager of employees (hierarchy problem) and were more focused on syntax rather than backend working of the join. So, according to my understanding, self join is joining the table to itself i.e. if I join a table to itself I can expect each record to be present twice in the newly formed table. But, if I self join table A why am I seeing only one count of Y?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong over here? Is there a tutorial or article where it has been explained easily?

Comment: Please act on my comment: Edit (not comment) your post to quote an authoritative definition of join & use it to justify what & why you expect what you expect from the smallest query that doesn't give what you expect, etc. PS Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. [ask] Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect research.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am new to coding and this is the first question I have posted on this forum. Thanks for your advice. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a duplicate is because there is no GROUP BY or DISTINCT clause in your query reducing the results to distinct rows based on the column value. Your query returns a count for every row of the table, that is normal.

The reason your results are different is because your joining on a different column, so if you are joining on the number column, you are counting the numbers, not the letters.

## TableA

If your raw table values are as follows:

`SELECT * FROM tableA;`

```
id | letter
-----------
1  | X
1  | T
2  | X
2  | T
3  | Y
```

### Example 1

You can manually write a query in your select statement as follows. Effectively, a separate query is performed for every row returned.

```
EXPLAIN -- show query breakdown
SELECT 
DISTINCT -- get distinct letter, no duplicate rows.
    a1.letter
  , (SELECT count(*) FROM tableA a2 WHERE a1.letter = a2.letter) letter_cnt
FROM
    tableA a1
;
```

This query is less effective, requiring two separate queries.

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | a1 | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | a2 | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | 20 | Using where |

```
letter | id
-----------
    X  | 2
    Y  | 1
    T  | 2
```

### Example 2

```
EXPLAIN -- show query breakdown
SELECT  
    a.letter
  , COUNT(a.letter) AS cnt 
FROM 
    tableA a 
GROUP BY 
    a.letter;
```

This method is more effective using one query and groups the first column giving you distinct letter rows.

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |

```
letter | letter
-----------
    T  | 2
    X  | 2
    Y  | 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.